# Nesting Functions in R

Tags: r, sorting, user-defined-functions, nested-loops, lapply

I am relatively new to R; and, I need help with a user defined function. I would like to see where each observation of a data frame ranks in a subset of similar observations of the same data frame. I'm having trouble referencing the original observation, in order to extract its rank, within my function.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("Alex Abrines", "Steven Adams", "Cole Aldrich", 
"LaMarcus Aldridge", "Kyle Anderson", "Ryan Anderson", "Giannis Antetokounmpo", 
"Carmelo Anthony", "OG Anunoby", "Darrell Arthur", "Will Barton", 
"Bradley Beal", "Davis Bertans", "Nemanja Bjelica", "Malcolm Brogdon", 
"Aaron Brooks", "Dillon Brooks", "Lorenzo Brown", "Sterling Brown", 
"Reggie Bullock", "Jimmy Butler", "Dwight Buycks", "Clint Capela", 
"Wilson Chandler", "Torrey Craig", "Jamal Crawford", "Deyonta Davis", 
"Matthew Dellavedova", "DeMar DeRozan", "Gorgui Dieng", "Andre Drummond", 
"James Ennis", "Kenneth Faried", "Raymond Felton", "Terrance Ferguson", 
"Bryn Forbes", "Tim Frazier", "Langston Galloway", "Marc Gasol", 
"Pau Gasol", "Paul George", "Marcus Georges-Hunt", "Taj Gibson", 
"Manu Ginobili", "Marcin Gortat", "Jerami Grant", "Danny Green", 
"Gerald Green", "JaMychal Green", "Blake Griffin", "James Harden", 
"Gary Harris", "Andrew Harrison", "Myke Henry", "John Henson", 
"Nene Hilario", "Darrun Hilliard", "Josh Huestis", "Serge Ibaka", 
"Stanley Johnson", "Nikola Jokic", "Tyus Jones", "Luke Kennard", 
"Sean Kilpatrick", "Joffrey Lauvergne", "Kyle Lowry", "Trey Lyles", 
"Ian Mahinmi", "Thon Maker", "Jarell Martin", "Luc Mbah a Moute", 
"Ben McLemore", "Jodie Meeks", "Khris Middleton", "Patty Mills", 
"Eric Moreland", "Markieff Morris", "Emmanuel Mudiay", "Shabazz Muhammad", 
"Xavier Munford", "Dejounte Murray", "Jamal Murray", "Lucas Nogueira", 
"Kelly Oubre", "Tony Parker", "Patrick Patterson", "Brandon Paul", 
"Chris Paul", "Marshall Plumlee", "Jakob Poeltl", "Otto Porter", 
"Norman Powell", "Willie Reed", "Tomas Satoransky", "Mike Scott", 
"Wayne Selden", "Pascal Siakam", "Ish Smith", "Tony Snell", "Jeff Teague", 
"Anthony Tolliver", "Karl-Anthony Towns", "P.J. Tucker", "Jonas Valanciunas", 
"Rashad Vaughn", "Russell Westbrook", "Andrew Wiggins", "D.J. Wilson", 
"Delon Wright"), Pos = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("C", "PF", "SF", "PG", "SG"
), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-02-01 *", class = "factor"), 
    Tm = structure(c(7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 
    1L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 
    4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 
    10L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 
    1L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 
    4L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 9L), .Label = c("DEN", 
    "DET", "HOU", "MEM", "MIL", "MIN", "OKC", "SAS", "TOR", "WAS"
    ), class = "factor"), Opp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    8L, 6L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 
    4L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 
    2L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
    9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 
    9L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 
    6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 10L), .Label = c("DEN", "DET", "HOU", "MEM", 
    "MIL", "MIN", "OKC", "SAS", "TOR", "WAS"), class = "factor"), 
    MP = c(29L, 32L, 3L, 34L, 30L, 29L, 36L, 34L, 21L, 1L, 36L, 
    38L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 3L, 32L, 11L, 24L, 35L, 40L, 19L, 35L, 
    34L, 22L, 17L, 15L, 25L, 38L, 13L, 28L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 4L, 
    18L, 17L, 4L, 33L, 20L, 36L, 6L, 33L, 20L, 26L, 25L, 28L, 
    30L, 20L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 34L, 22L, 32L, 13L, 8L, 12L, 35L, 
    36L, 37L, 17L, 21L, 18L, 2L, 35L, 15L, 19L, 13L, 28L, 35L, 
    10L, 9L, 35L, 24L, 5L, 32L, 14L, 3L, 7L, 24L, 34L, 3L, 23L, 
    17L, 15L, 2L, 30L, 5L, 16L, 29L, 26L, 5L, 28L, 19L, 31L, 
    13L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 33L, 31L, 29L, 4L, 39L, 30L, 4L, 
    13L), Player.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
    32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 
    44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 52L, 54L, 55L, 
    56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
    68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
    80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
    92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
    103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L), .Label = c("abrinal01", 
    "adamsst01", "aldrico01", "aldrila01", "anderky01", "anderry01", 
    "antetgi01", "anthoca01", "anunoog01", "arthuda01", "bartowi01", 
    "bealbr01", "bertada01", "bjeline01", "brogdma01", "brookaa01", 
    "brookdi01", "brownlo01", "brownst02", "bullore01", "butleji01", 
    "buyckdw01", "capelca01", "chandwi01", "craigto01", "crawfja01", 
    "davisde01", "dellama01", "derozde01", "dienggo01", "drumman01", 
    "ennisja01", "farieke01", "feltora01", "fergute01", "forbebr01", 
    "fraziti01", "gallola01", "gasolma01", "gasolpa01", "georgma01", 
    "georgpa01", "gibsota01", "ginobma01", "gortama01", "grantje01", 
    "greenda02", "greenge01", "greenja01", "griffbl01", "hardeja01", 
    "harrian01", "harriga01", "henrymy01", "hensojo01", "hilarne01", 
    "hillida01", "huestjo01", "ibakase01", "johnsst04", "jokicni01", 
    "jonesty01", "kennalu01", "kilpase01", "lauvejo01", "lowryky01", 
    "lylestr01", "mahinia01", "makerth01", "martija01", "mbahalu01", 
    "mclembe01", "meeksjo01", "middlkh01", "millspa02", "moreler01", 
    "morrima02", "mudiaem01", "muhamsh01", "munfoxa02", "murrade01", 
    "murraja01", "noguelu01", "oubreke01", "parketo01", "pattepa01", 
    "paulbr01", "paulch01", "plumlma02", "poeltja01", "porteot01", 
    "powelno01", "reedwi02", "satorto01", "scottmi01", "seldewa01", 
    "siakapa01", "smithis01", "snellto01", "teaguje01", "tollian01", 
    "townska01", "tuckepj01", "valanjo01", "vaughra01", "westbru01", 
    "wiggian01", "wilsodj01", "wrighde01"), class = "factor"), 
    Game.ID = structure(c(7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
    1L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 
    2L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
    1L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 
    8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 
    10L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
    9L), .Label = c("2018-02-01 * DEN", "2018-02-01 * DET", "2018-02-01 * HOU", 
    "2018-02-01 * MEM", "2018-02-01 * MIL", "2018-02-01 * MIN", 
    "2018-02-01 * OKC", "2018-02-01 * SAS", "2018-02-01 * TOR", 
    "2018-02-01 * WAS"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Pos", "Date", "Tm", "Opp", "MP", "Player.ID", "Game.ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
109L))
```

I would like to write a function that, for each observation:

```
> df[1, ]
          Name Pos         Date  Tm Opp MP Player.ID          Game.ID
1 Alex Abrines  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 29 abrinal01 2018-02-01 * OKC
```

creates a subset of all other observations with a matching `df$Game.ID`.

```
> df[df$Game.ID == '2018-02-01 * OKC', ]
                 Name Pos         Date  Tm Opp MP Player.ID          Game.ID
1        Alex Abrines  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 29 abrinal01 2018-02-01 * OKC
2        Steven Adams   C 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 32 adamsst01 2018-02-01 * OKC
8     Carmelo Anthony  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 34 anthoca01 2018-02-01 * OKC
34     Raymond Felton  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 14 feltora01 2018-02-01 * OKC
35  Terrance Ferguson  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN  4 fergute01 2018-02-01 * OKC
41        Paul George  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 36 georgpa01 2018-02-01 * OKC
46       Jerami Grant  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 25 grantje01 2018-02-01 * OKC
58       Josh Huestis  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 12 huestjo01 2018-02-01 * OKC
86  Patrick Patterson  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 15 pattepa01 2018-02-01 * OKC
106 Russell Westbrook  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 39 westbru01 2018-02-01 * OKC
```

and then returns the rank of the original observation's `df$MP`

```
> df[1, c('MP')]
[1] 29
```

in the hierarchy of the new subset.

```
> xx <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df[df$Game.ID == '2018-02-01 * OKC', c('MP')], decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df[df$Game.ID == '2018-02-01 * OKC', c('MP')], decreasing = TRUE)))))
> xx
   X1 X2
1  39  1
2  36  2
3  34  3
4  32  4
5  29  5
6  25  6
7  15  7
8  14  8
9  12  9
10  4 10
> colnames(xx) <- c('MP', 'Depth.Chart')
> yy <- df[df$Game.ID == '2018-02-01 * OKC', ]
> yy
                 Name Pos         Date  Tm Opp MP Player.ID
1        Alex Abrines  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 29 abrinal01
2        Steven Adams   C 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 32 adamsst01
8     Carmelo Anthony  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 34 anthoca01
34     Raymond Felton  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 14 feltora01
35  Terrance Ferguson  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN  4 fergute01
41        Paul George  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 36 georgpa01
46       Jerami Grant  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 25 grantje01
58       Josh Huestis  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 12 huestjo01
86  Patrick Patterson  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 15 pattepa01
106 Russell Westbrook  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN 39 westbru01
             Game.ID
1   2018-02-01 * OKC
2   2018-02-01 * OKC
8   2018-02-01 * OKC
34  2018-02-01 * OKC
35  2018-02-01 * OKC
41  2018-02-01 * OKC
46  2018-02-01 * OKC
58  2018-02-01 * OKC
86  2018-02-01 * OKC
106 2018-02-01 * OKC
> zz <- merge(yy, xx, all.x = TRUE)
> zz
   MP              Name Pos         Date  Tm Opp Player.ID
1   4 Terrance Ferguson  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN fergute01
2  12      Josh Huestis  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN huestjo01
3  14    Raymond Felton  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN feltora01
4  15 Patrick Patterson  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN pattepa01
5  25      Jerami Grant  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN grantje01
6  29      Alex Abrines  SG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN abrinal01
7  32      Steven Adams   C 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN adamsst01
8  34   Carmelo Anthony  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN anthoca01
9  36       Paul George  PF 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN georgpa01
10 39 Russell Westbrook  PG 2018-02-01 * OKC DEN westbru01
            Game.ID Depth.Chart
1  2018-02-01 * OKC          10
2  2018-02-01 * OKC           9
3  2018-02-01 * OKC           8
4  2018-02-01 * OKC           7
5  2018-02-01 * OKC           6
6  2018-02-01 * OKC           5
7  2018-02-01 * OKC           4
8  2018-02-01 * OKC           3
9  2018-02-01 * OKC           2
10 2018-02-01 * OKC           1
```

Finally, I need to extract the value of `zz$Depth.Chart` that corresponds to the original observation, `5`.

```
> zz[zz$MP == 29, c('Depth.Chart')]
[1] 5
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I would like to define a function that executes the laborious and messy steps above for each observation in a data frame and returns a vector of the results. How can I reference the value of `df$MP` that corresponds to the observation I'm working on without explicitly calling it `29`, like I do above? Here are a few of the thing I've tried, unsuccessfully.

```
> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[i, 2]
+   })}
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 6
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 8
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
[1] 8
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
[1] 3
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[7]]
[1] 5
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
[1] 7
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
[1] 9
Levels: 1 10 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
[1] 1
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[df3$X1 == i, 2]
+   })}
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in Ops.factor(df3$X1, i) : level sets of factors are different 
7.
stop("level sets of factors are different") 
6.
Ops.factor(df3$X1, i) 
5.
`[.data.frame`(df3, df3$X1 == i, 2) 
4.
df3[df3$X1 == i, 2] 
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2.
lapply(col1, function(i) {
    df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
    df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, 
        decreasing = TRUE))))) ... 
1.
f1(df$Game.ID, df, c("MP")) 

> f1 <- function(col1, df, col2){
+   lapply(col1, function(i){
+     df2 <- df[col1 == i, col2]
+     df3 <- data.frame(cbind(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE), rownames(data.table(sort(df2, decreasing = TRUE)))))
+     df3[col2 == i, 2]
+   })}
> f1(df$Game.ID, df, c('MP'))[1:10]
[[1]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[4]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[6]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[7]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 12 13 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[8]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[9]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[10]]
factor(0)
Levels: 1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I guess I don't fully understand how R treats this `i` variable inside the function; or, therefore, how reference it appropriately. In looking through this forum, I found generic examples of nesting functions inside of functions in Python but not in R. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is a simpler subset of my data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(MP = c(29L, 32L, 3L, 34L, 14L, 3L, 40L, 17L, 13L, 
14L, 4L, 36L, 6L, 33L, 25L, 12L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 28L, 33L, 39L, 
30L), Player.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 21L, 
26L, 30L, 34L, 35L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 62L, 79L, 86L, 100L, 
102L, 106L, 107L), .Label = c("abrinal01", "adamsst01", "aldrico01", 
"aldrila01", "anderky01", "anderry01", "antetgi01", "anthoca01", 
"anunoog01", "arthuda01", "bartowi01", "bealbr01", "bertada01", 
"bjeline01", "brogdma01", "brookaa01", "brookdi01", "brownlo01", 
"brownst02", "bullore01", "butleji01", "buyckdw01", "capelca01", 
"chandwi01", "craigto01", "crawfja01", "davisde01", "dellama01", 
"derozde01", "dienggo01", "drumman01", "ennisja01", "farieke01", 
"feltora01", "fergute01", "forbebr01", "fraziti01", "gallola01", 
"gasolma01", "gasolpa01", "georgma01", "georgpa01", "gibsota01", 
"ginobma01", "gortama01", "grantje01", "greenda02", "greenge01", 
"greenja01", "griffbl01", "hardeja01", "harrian01", "harriga01", 
"henrymy01", "hensojo01", "hilarne01", "hillida01", "huestjo01", 
"ibakase01", "johnsst04", "jokicni01", "jonesty01", "kennalu01", 
"kilpase01", "lauvejo01", "lowryky01", "lylestr01", "mahinia01", 
"makerth01", "martija01", "mbahalu01", "mclembe01", "meeksjo01", 
"middlkh01", "millspa02", "moreler01", "morrima02", "mudiaem01", 
"muhamsh01", "munfoxa02", "murrade01", "murraja01", "noguelu01", 
"oubreke01", "parketo01", "pattepa01", "paulbr01", "paulch01", 
"plumlma02", "poeltja01", "porteot01", "powelno01", "reedwi02", 
"satorto01", "scottmi01", "seldewa01", "siakapa01", "smithis01", 
"snellto01", "teaguje01", "tollian01", "townska01", "tuckepj01", 
"valanjo01", "vaughra01", "westbru01", "wiggian01", "wilsodj01", 
"wrighde01"), class = "factor"), Game.ID = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("2018-02-01 * DEN", "2018-02-01 * DET", 
"2018-02-01 * HOU", "2018-02-01 * MEM", "2018-02-01 * MIL", "2018-02-01 * MIN", 
"2018-02-01 * OKC", "2018-02-01 * SAS", "2018-02-01 * TOR", "2018-02-01 * WAS"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MP", "Player.ID", "Game.ID"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 30L, 34L, 
35L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 62L, 79L, 86L, 100L, 102L, 106L, 
107L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It might be helpful to construct a smaller, easier to understand example. Sometimes by doing that you can solve the issue yourself.  R scoping rules are very simple.  Each function defines it's own frame.  If `i` exists in the functions frame, it uses that variable.  If it doesn't exist, it looks in the parent frame.  If that doesn't exist, it looks in the parent's parent, and so on until it gets to the global frame.

Comment: Strongly agreed with thc. For example data **thank you for using `dput`!**, but also please make a *minimal* example. Don't share 100 rows and 8 columns when 10 rows and 3 columns would do. Looks to me like we need Game ID, Player Id, and MP for the ranking, and that's it for columns. For rows, 3 or 4 rows for each of 2 Game ID's is plenty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `data.table` for little steps in your process, but you should just use it for the whole thing. It's very convenient for doing operations "by group", in this case using `rank()` by `Game.ID`. Using your small sample data:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Depth.Chart := rank(-MP), by = Game.ID]
df
#     MP Player.ID          Game.ID Depth.Chart
#  1: 29 abrinal01 2018-02-01 * OKC         5.0
#  2: 32 adamsst01 2018-02-01 * OKC         4.0
#  3:  3 aldrico01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
#  4: 34 anthoca01 2018-02-01 * OKC         3.0
#  5: 14 bjeline01 2018-02-01 * MIN         8.0
#  6:  3 brookaa01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
#  7: 40 butleji01 2018-02-01 * MIN         1.0
#  8: 17 crawfja01 2018-02-01 * MIN         6.5
#  9: 13 dienggo01 2018-02-01 * MIN         9.0
# 10: 14 feltora01 2018-02-01 * OKC         8.0
# 11:  4 fergute01 2018-02-01 * OKC        10.0
# 12: 36 georgpa01 2018-02-01 * OKC         2.0
# 13:  6 georgma01 2018-02-01 * MIN        10.0
# 14: 33 gibsota01 2018-02-01 * MIN         2.5
# 15: 25 grantje01 2018-02-01 * OKC         6.0
# 16: 12 huestjo01 2018-02-01 * OKC         9.0
# 17: 17 jonesty01 2018-02-01 * MIN         6.5
# 18:  3 muhamsh01 2018-02-01 * MIN        12.0
# 19: 15 pattepa01 2018-02-01 * OKC         7.0
# 20: 28 teaguje01 2018-02-01 * MIN         5.0
# 21: 33 townska01 2018-02-01 * MIN         2.5
# 22: 39 westbru01 2018-02-01 * OKC         1.0
# 23: 30 wiggian01 2018-02-01 * MIN         4.0
#     MP Player.ID          Game.ID Depth.Chart
```

`rank`, by default, averages ties, but see `?rank` for other options.